# Advanced Search with linq To sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I'm working on my first ASP.net MVC apps, in this apps i got to type of search Simple and Advanced :

> Simple search olny dd,df and gov are required
>   
>  Advanced search user got more options, even in advanced search dd,df and gov are required field.

So this is my Search Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult search(LogModel.Search soption)
    {
        // this part will not change the same in simple and advenced
        DateTime dd1 = soption.dd;
        DateTime df1 = soption.df;
        var model = (from p in entity.vehicule                        
                     where p.agence.idgov == soption.gov
                     where !p.indisponible.Any(b => (dd1 >= b.Dd && dd1 <= b.Df) || (df1 >= b.Dd && df1 <= b.Df))
                     where !p.indisponible.Any(c => (c.Dd >= dd1 && c.Dd <= df1) || (c.Df >= dd1 && c.Df <= df1))
                     select p).ToList();


        // here i want to add my filtring action advanced search
        if (!soption.mark)
            model = model.Any(b => b.idmarque == soption.mark );


        return View(model);

    }
```

the simple search mode work so fine but now i'm trying to implement the advanced search and this is what i got in my mind :

> **If** model.myVar is not null(that mean user has puted something )
>   
>  **then** i'm gonna filter some result from my pricinple model search request.

So I'm wondring if i got right ? also this line is underlined with red :

```
model = model.Any(b => b.idmarque == soption.mark );
```

Impossible to convert type bool to Systeme.collection.generic.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a where clause again

```
if (!soption.mark) 
            model = from x in model
                    where (b => b.idmarque == soption.mark )
                    select x
```

Answer (score 0):

Any() method of model returns bool. You can try select()

Comment: FirstOrDefault() wil return only the first data find but me i want to get all data.